# Pointers on Android AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I am asking some code pointer's to implement this feature:

Suppose there's a text box allows user to type in tweet message to send. Only when user type in `@` the app should show the auto-complete drop down to let user pick item from the list.

Example from the Internet below to give a better idea about what I am talking about:

[image]

I am just asking for some code examples, guidelines or any information that could help me get started on implementing something like this.

Thank you!

Comment: [have you tried Google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+autocompletetextview+example)

Comment: @panini yes, but this is not exactly the same as the original AutoCompleteTextView. Or would you suggest a way to override the AutoCompleteTextViewclass to get the functionality I am looking for?